# routerLinkActive not working for navigation bar

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am using angular 12 and trying to make navigation bar activation dynamic but it is not working

**Code**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" >
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" style="color: blue;">User Name</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" routerLinkActive="active" href="" >Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" (click)=onAdminProject() >Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" (click)=onAdminAccount()  >Account</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active"  >Courses</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" (click)= onAdminAbout() >About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**.ts on AdminProject()**

```
 onAdminProject(){
    this.account=false
    this.projectsdisplay=true
    this.about=false
    
  }
```

Please help

Comment: are the button clicks redirecting you to different routes? Please provide an MVE on what's not working

Comment: that type of route is used in button click

Comment: You need to define something like this, because I don't see any of your routes added to the HTML.
`routerLink="/user/bob" routerLinkActive="active"`
And you don't need to add click event for routing

Comment: Please show the code for `onAdminProject()`

Comment: added  onAdminProject()

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light " >
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" style="color: blue;">User Name</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" routerLink="/slider" routerLinkActive="active" >Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/amcharts" routerLinkActive="active"   (click)=onAdminProject() >Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/gallery" routerLinkActive="active" (click)=onAdminAccount()  >Account</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/notification" routerLinkActive="active"  >Courses</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link"routerLink="/filter" routerLinkActive="active" (click)= onAdminAbout() >About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please explain what you changed in the code and why it would solve OP issue

Comment: Add routerLink to navigate around components `routerLink="/amcharts"`

Answer (score 0):

`routerLinkActive` only makes sense if you have a `routerLink` on the same element or one of its child.

Your links does not use `routerLink` at all.